# KableExtra: colortbl's \cellcolor not filling entire cell when used in combination with \makecell

Tags: r, latex, kable, kableextra

I'm looking for a workaround solution for a [known issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437733/colortbls-cellcolor-not-filling-whole-cell-in-combination-with-makecell) where \cellcolor from the `colortbl` package does not work properly with \makecell. As mentioned, there probably already exists a workaround in Latex, but I'm hoping for a solution in terms of the R package `kableExtra` when producing pdfs using `rmarkdown`. Here's a screenshot; as can be seen, some cells are not filled entirely.

[image]

Here's a minimally reproducible example in `rmarkdown`:

```
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
# Data --------------------------------------------------------------------
df <- tribble(
  ~col1, ~col2, 
  "really long text that needs to be broken into multiple lines so it can fit", 4,
  "really long text that needs to be broken", 4,
  "really long text that needs a fix", 4,
) %>%
  modify_at(
    .x = .,
    .at = 1,
    .f = stringr::str_wrap,
    width = 25
  )
# Table -------------------------------------------------------------------
df %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = 1, .fns = linebreak, align = "l")) %>%
  kbl(x = ., escape = FALSE) %>%
  row_spec(row = 1:3, background = "#e5e5e5")
```

One possible fix is to specify `keep_tex: true` in the YAML and fix the issue in the .tex file manually before using pandoc. But I'm generating many tables and this can't possibly be efficient. Any suggestion of a potential workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not what you asked, but note that with huxtable this is almost a one-liner: `as_hux(df) %>% set_width(.5) %>% set_all_borders() %>% set_background_color(everywhere, 1, "#e5e5e5")` with no nasty white bits...

Comment: 'Preciate the pointer. I actually switched to `flextable` anyways since my company wants to stay in docx/google doc. But I'll check out `huxtable` too. Always good to have more options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `column_spec` to force the line wrap rather than using `makecell` and `linewrap`?...

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr) #for the pipe
library(kableExtra)


df <- tribble(
  ~col1, ~col2, 
  "really long text that needs to be broken into multiple lines so it can fit", 4,
  "really long text that needs to be broken", 4,
  "really long text that needs a fix", 4,
)


kbl(df) %>%
  column_spec(1, width = "30mm") %>% 
  row_spec(row = 1:3, background = "#e5e5e5")
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good approach, which is also my initial approach. But my real example involves a lot of formatting (styling, hold position, and even a while loop for conditional formatting, etc.), and, after all of that, specifying the width via column_spec no longer works (might have to investigate a little); this is why I switched to using `stringr`. I'll wait a bit and come back to accept your solution since you made a good point that it's probably easier to figure out what's causing column_spec to not work than trying to figure out how to fix a bigger problem with `\makecell`.

Comment: It's probably worth trying to workout what is causing `column_spec` `width` to fail in your use case. I've found it to be a robust method, and simpler than others. Might be worth adding a new question with the actual use case and the problems you are having to negotiate.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that worked for **my use case** (where `column_spec(width)` fails), is based on leandriis's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437733/colortbls-cellcolor-not-filling-whole-cell-in-combination-with-makecell) in this post. Specifically, we wrap the `\colorbox` command around the `\makecell` command to have a completely colored cell. For example `\colorbox[HTML]{hexcode}{\makecell{text}}`. This requires that we create our own custom `linebreak` function, which not only wraps our text in `\makecell` but also wraps that latex code in a `\colorbox`.

```
# Custom linebreak --------------------------------------------------------
linebreak_custom <- function(x, align = "l", linebreaker = "\n") {
  ifelse(
    # If '\n' is detected in a string, TRUE, or else FALSE
    test = str_detect(x, linebreaker),
    # For TRUE's, wrap text in \makecell and then in \colorbox
    yes = paste0(
      "\\cellcolor[HTML]{e5e5e5}{\\colorbox[HTML]{e5e5e5}{\\makecell[", align, "]{",
      str_replace_all(x, linebreaker, "\\\\\\\\"), "}}}"
    ),
    # Return as is if no '\n' detected
    no = x
  )
}
# Data --------------------------------------------------------------------
df <- tribble(
  ~col1, ~col2,
  "really long text that needs to be broken into multiple lines so it can fit", 4,
  "really long text that needs to be broken", 4,
  "really long text that needs a fix", 4,
) %>%
  modify_at(
    .x = .,
    .at = 1,
    .f = stringr::str_wrap,
    width = 25
  )
# Table -------------------------------------------------------------------
df %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = 1, .fns = linebreak_custom, align = "l")) %>%
  kbl(x = ., escape = FALSE) %>%
  row_spec(row = 1:3, background = "#e5e5e5")
```

This produces the desired output:

[image]

**As noted, this solution may not be robust to future versions of kableExtra (as it involves, quite frankly, "hacking" the source code), and the solution suggested by Peter above should still be better in many use cases.** I've created an issue via Github to bring this to their attention, so perhaps there could be an official fix in **their** code in the future.